# checking the adjacent column value in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a **films** database with multiple columns, within this is 4 columns.

```
director_surname |  director_firstname | producer_surname |  producer_firstname |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    frost        |    phil             |    wilson        |    john             |

    brendon      |    john             |    lee           |    tommey           |

    wilson       |    mark             |    allen         |    jill             |
```

I would now like to do a select statement that looks for a name in the **surname** columns then checks the **firstname** column for a value.

So if the search was **wilson, john** I only want to bring back that row. So far I have this, which is fine for the **surname** select.

```
SELECT * FROM films 
WHERE CONCAT(director_surname, producer_surname) 
LIKE '%wilson%';
```

This is where I'm a bit stuck. I've tried an **AND** statement but this also brings back all the rows with **john** as a **firstname**. I'm thinking an **ORDER BY IF** statement may do it, but I can get it to work..

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: First see normalisation - who directed *Paris, je t'aime* or *Four Rooms* or even *The Wizard of Oz*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    films 
WHERE
    (
        director_sirname = 'wilson'
        AND director_firstname = 'john'
    ) OR
    (
        producer_sirname = 'wilson'
        AND producer_firstname = 'john'
    )
;
```